# Private Sub olSentItems_ItemAdd(ByVal Item As Object) only runs for default Outlook account

Tags: vba, outlook

The below code only runs when sending an email with the default account within Outloo. How can I get it to run whatever account the message is being sent from?

```
Private Sub olSentItems_ItemAdd(ByVal Item As Object)

On Error Resume Next

Dim strPrompt As String

strPrompt = "Do you want to flag this message for followup?"

If MsgBox(strPrompt, vbYesNo + vbQuestion + vbMsgBoxSetForeground, "Add flag?") = vbYes Then

    Dim strDays As String
    Dim intDays As Integer
    Dim strFollowMessage As String
    Dim dteDue As Date

    strDays = InputBox("Days?", , 3)


    intDays = Val(strDays)

    strFollowMessage = InputBox("Message?", , "PRH FollowUp")

    With Item

        .IsMarkedAsTask

        .MarkAsTask olMarkNoDate

        dteDue = Now + intDays

        .TaskDueDate = dteDue
        .TaskStartDate = dteDue
        .FlagRequest = strFollowMessage
        .ReminderSet = False

        .Save

    End With

End If

End Sub
```

I am at a loss to know how to resolve?

Answer (score 0):

You need to subscribe to the Sent Items folder of each account where you need to handle outgoing emails. To get the Sent Items folder of a specific account configured in Outlook you need to use the [Store.GetDefaultFolder](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/outlook.store.getdefaultfolder) method which returns a `Folder` object that represents the default folder in the store and that is of the type specified by the `FolderType` argument. This method is similar to the `GetDefaultFolder` method of the `NameSpace` object. The difference is that this method gets the default folder on the delivery store that is associated with the account, whereas `NameSpace.GetDefaultFolder` returns the default folder on the default store for the current profile.

To get all stores in the profile you can use the [NameSpace.Stores](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/outlook.namespace.stores) property which returns a `Stores` collection object that represents all the `Store` objects in the current profile. For example:

```
Sub EnumerateFoldersInStores() 
 Dim colStores As Outlook.Stores 
 Dim oStore As Outlook.Store 
 Dim oRoot As Outlook.Folder 
 
 On Error Resume Next 
 Set colStores = Application.Session.Stores 
 For Each oStore In colStores 
   Set oRoot = oStore.GetRootFolder 
   Debug.Print (oRoot.FolderPath) 
   EnumerateFolders oRoot 
 Next 
End Sub 

Private Sub EnumerateFolders(ByVal oFolder As Outlook.Folder) 
 Dim folders As Outlook.folders 
 Dim Folder As Outlook.Folder 
 Dim foldercount As Integer 
 
 On Error Resume Next 
 
 Set folders = oFolder.folders 
 foldercount = folders.Count 
 'Check if there are any folders below oFolder 
 If foldercount Then 
   For Each Folder In folders 
     Debug.Print (Folder.FolderPath) 
     EnumerateFolders Folder 
   Next 
 End If 
End Sub
```